# My function is not defined properly, can anyone tell me why?

Tags: python, function, scope

I have a main function, and a getDogYears function that contains the variable dogYears. I have tried moving getDogYears above the main function, and I have tried initializing dogYears in the main function. I know dogYears is outside the scope of the main function, so can anyone tell me how I can make my main function be able to display information found in getDogYears? I'm sure it's something silly, but it would be a great lesson for me. Thank you!

The error: Traceback (most recent call last):
line 38, in 
main()
line 21, in main
format(dogYears, ",.1f"), "in dog years.")
NameError: name 'dogYears' is not defined. Did you mean: 'getDogYears'?

````
FIRST_YEAR_EQUIV = 15
SECOND_YEAR_EQUIV = 9
THREE_PLUS_YEARS_MULTIPLIER = 5

def main():
    print("This program calculate's a dog's approximate age in \"dog years\" based on human years.\n")

    humanYears = float(input("Dog's age in human years? "))

    while humanYears < 0:
        print("\nHuman age must be a positive number.")
        humanYears = float(input("Dog's age in human years? "))
    else:
        getDogYears(humanYears)

        # end if
    print("\nA dog with a human age of", format(humanYears, ",.1f"), "years is", 
    format(dogYears, ",.1f"), "in dog years.")


def getDogYears(humanYears):
    if humanYears <= 1:
        dogYears = FIRST_YEAR_EQUIV * humanYears
    elif humanYears <= 2:
        dogYears = FIRST_YEAR_EQUIV + SECOND_YEAR_EQUIV * (humanYears - 1)
    else:
        dogYears = FIRST_YEAR_EQUIV + SECOND_YEAR_EQUIV + THREE_PLUS_YEARS_MULTIPLIER * (humanYears - 2)


# DO NOT MODIFY CODE BELOW THIS LINE
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() ```
````

Comment: `getDogYears()` should `return` the value you want to use. This will let you get the value in the main function `dogYears = getDogYears(humanYears)`.

Comment: `dogYears` is a local variable to the `getDogYears` function.  When the function returns, the variable disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `return` dog years from `getDogYears()`, and do `dogYears = getDogYears(humanYears)` inside the `main()` function.

```
FIRST_YEAR_EQUIV = 15
SECOND_YEAR_EQUIV = 9
THREE_PLUS_YEARS_MULTIPLIER = 5

def main():
    print("This program calculate's a dog's approximate age in \"dog years\" based on human years.\n")

    humanYears = float(input("Dog's age in human years? "))

    while humanYears < 0:
        print("\nHuman age must be a positive number.")
        humanYears = float(input("Dog's age in human years? "))
    else:
        dogYears = getDogYears(humanYears)

        # end if
    print("\nA dog with a human age of", format(humanYears, ",.1f"), "years is", 
    format(dogYears, ",.1f"), "in dog years.")


def getDogYears(humanYears):
    if humanYears <= 1:
        dogYears = FIRST_YEAR_EQUIV * humanYears
    elif humanYears <= 2:
        dogYears = FIRST_YEAR_EQUIV + SECOND_YEAR_EQUIV * (humanYears - 1)
    else:
        dogYears = FIRST_YEAR_EQUIV + SECOND_YEAR_EQUIV + THREE_PLUS_YEARS_MULTIPLIER * (humanYears - 2)
    return dogYears
```